Trouble proving a theorem using induction in Coq
Theorem five_and_three: forall i, exists a b, i + 8 = 3 * a + 5 * b.

I'm currently using these tactics:
intro i.
induction i as [| i' IH].
exists 1, 1.
simpl.
reflexivity.

And I'm stuck with this goal:
1 goal
i' : nat
IH : exists a b : nat, i' + 8 = 3 * a + 5 * b
______________________________________(1/1)
exists a b : nat, S i' + 8 = 3 * a + 5 * b

My goal is practically the same as my hypothesis minus the fact that the goal is  using S i' instead of i' but I'm unsure on what to do now.

This is the usual way an induction step works in any proof by induction: you assume something of i' and have to prove it for S i'. But in your specific case I'm not sure induction is the way to go. Do you know how to prove this theorem on paper? Does this proof go by induction? If the first answer is no, then Coq will not magically help. If the second is no, then you should try to reproduce your proof structure. If both answers are yes, can you tell us informally how you would do this part of the proof?

To make @MevenLennon-Bertrand's suggestion more explicit: suppose you have $a'$ and $b'$ such that $i + 8 = 3 a' + 5 b'$. Can you easily write down $a$ and $b$ (depending on $a'$ and $b'$) such that $(i + 1) + 8 = 3 a + 5 b$? If not, you should not be trying to use induction. If yes destruct IH as [a' [b' H]] is your friend.

I guess you may want to first prove Bezout's identity in Coq.
